# How to run React-Native Examples?

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I can't find any instructions on how to install and run one of the other Examples provided in 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples' such as 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies'.

The tutorial only tells you to do

`react-native init AwesomeProject`

which grabs 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/SampleApp'.

---

If I clone the entire 'react-native' repository, and then run

```
npm install
npm start
```

From the root folder (i.e. '/react-native'), and then open '/react-native/Examples/Movies/Movies.xcodeproj' in Xcode, and Run the project, it seems to build fine. The Simulator comes up, shows a "Movies" intro screen for the app, but then the red screen of death appears with a print out of:

```
:0
```

and Terminal, where 'npm start' is running at the root folder, prints out:

```
Error: EISDIR, read
    at Error (native)
[02:35:02] <START> request:/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.includeRequire.runModule.bundle
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should work just by following the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), except that you have to run `npm install` inside your react-native directory.

Then just run for example the Movie Project with Xcode.

If you want to "isolate" the MovieProject or another react-native example project, the easy way is to init a new react native app (`react-native init MyAppName`) and just copy the JS files from the example project (in the example below the Movie Project) into the new app folder.

And then don't forget to edit your iOS/AppDelegate.m file.

You have to edit 2 lines:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```

By:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/MoviesApp.bundle"];
```

AND

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"MyAppName"
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

By:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"MoviesApp"
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

---

Comment: I know this answer is older, and maybe my question is stupid, but what do you mean with "isolate the app" what is the difference with `react-native init` and the `npm install`?

Answer (score 6):

First, meet the [requirements](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#requirements) on the getting started guide

Then, check out the [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) repository and run the following inside it:

1. `npm install`
2. `open Examples/Movies/Movies.xcodeproj`

If you have errors compiling due to linking errors, removing the derived data may help. Quit Xcode, delete `/Users/{you}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, and re-open Xcode.

Comment: I tried this with `UIExplorer`, it successfully built but I encountered an error: `Could not find source file at Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerApp.ios.js`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed my issue by running `npm start` after `npm install`, then open xcode project.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can run the android version of the UIExplorer app by running the command:

```
./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug
./packager/packager.sh
```

or this:

```
./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug
./packager/packager.sh
```

for the movies example (should be run on the react-native folder).

Also, you could run the gradle daemon to speed up the build time for Android.

Comment: English sentences should end with ".", "?" or "!". It is not a chatroom. But your content is worthy, so I fixed it and voted it up. I would be happier if I had to do only the second next time :-) .

Comment: @peterh I will pay more attention to these kind of details, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install node.js in your Terminal with

```
brew install node
```

ReactNative use Node.js to build the Javascript code inside the project.

Then you need Watchman, a file watcher from Facebook with

```
brew install watchman
```

React Native use Watchman to rebuild your code when there's a change in it.

The final thing is to install and run node with a Terminal window in the react-native folder.

```
npm install
npm start
```

Now you can open a project from the react-native/Examples folder in Xcode, then build and run it.

Comment: Doing 'npm start' inside /Examples/Moveis I get: npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.3
npm ERR! path /Users/.../React/Examples/Movies/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/.../React/Examples/Movies/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!  /Users/.../npm-debug.log

Comment: yes, my fault. You had to run npm install and npm start in the react-native folder. I edited my answer

Comment: So I think I got a step closer. I downloaded the entire 'react-native-master' folder from GitHub. At the root ran 'npm install' and 'npm start', then opened /react-native-master/Examples/Movies in Xcode and ran it with no build errors. Now I get the Red Screen of Death with the only message being ":0". Terminal prints out:    Error: EISDIR, read at Error (native)
<START> request:/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.includeRequire.runModule.bundle

Comment: My react native folder is "react-native" without the "master" name in it.  I clone the git repo with the Terminal. Try this way and let me know.

Comment: Same exact behavior when cloning the git repo. Run the project, and in the simulator I get an intro screen that say "Movies" and Facebook Copyright info, and then a second or two later the Red Screen of Death appears. Terminal prints out _Error: EISDIR, read
    at Error (native)
[03:24:33] <START> request:/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.includeRequire.runModule.bundle_

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I suggest you to open an issue on the React-Native github page to solve the problem. With this settings I'm working fine with React-Native.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open your terminal and cd to the specific example you want to run
cd home/XYZ/react-native-master/Examples/UIExplorer

2) run npm install

3) run npm start

4) Open the example in Xcode and run it from there
It should work fine.

PS: It was so simple but a lot of answers mislead me too.

Answer (score 1):

1. brew update
2. brew install node
3. brew upgrade node (if u already installed)
4. brew install watchman
5. npm install -g react-native-cli
6. react-native init [name ur app] --version 0.24.0(depends on which version u want to use, if it didn't work use below)
   (6). react-native init [name ur app] --verbose
7. cd [name ur app]
8. open .
9. npm start
10. atom . (if u installed atom)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step tutorial for creating a simple application.

1) First download the cli tool

2) npm run start

3) start the app in the xcode IOS simulator.

Tutorial here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/553844b55bbbb6000031f0f9

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this for people just trying to run an existing react-native project/app like me:

In Terminal:

1. npm install
2. npm start (should open a separate window to run react package manager or it may use the existing terminal window, if that is the case you will need to open a new terminal window to type the command for step 3)
3. react-native run-ios/react-native run-android

**you may want to run npm update -g (while in the react native folder) to ensure all the npm packages are up to date before running npm install

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10 I had to do `adb shell am start -n com.facebook.react.movies/.MoviesActivity` to get the examples running.
(make sure `ANDROID_SDK\platform-tools` is in path or run command with absolute path)

So step by step I had to do:

```
cd react-native

./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug

adb shell am start -n com.facebook.react.movies/.MoviesActivity

./packager/packager.sh
```

or

```
./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug

adb shell am start -n com.facebook.react.uiapp/.UIExplorerActivity

./packager/packager.sh
```