# react-native app not working in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

Hi I have downloaded this sample app  https://github.com/iZaL/my-appointment . when i am runing this getting error .can you help me on this issue
my-appointment-master/src/containers/Category/Category.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/react-native-alphabetlistview and its parent directories

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
i have tried to reset this all but getting same issue

Comment: You should update the question with your error log.

Comment: you can try the answers over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327219/how-to-run-react-native-examples?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project package.json is missing the dependency
`react-native-alphabetlistview`.

You can install it via 
`npm install react-native-alphabetlistview  --save`